# How to allow incoming traffic based on User-Agent Header field with Apache

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, setenvif

I have [read the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) on Apache's setEnvIf and, using their example, written the following httpd config file designed to only allow requests from HTTP Header User-Agent=Doug

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent Doug let_me_in
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=let_me_in
</Directory>
```

Upon using Postman to send the request with the User-Agent being Doug, the request was denied. I have also tried switching the order to allow,deny to no avail.

I am running Amazon AMI and using Apache 2.2.31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Postman in terms of setting User-Agent HTTP header. I had the Apache configuration correct after all.